# proofread $\left \| f -g\right \|_{p}^{p}=p(p-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t}[m(f>t/g>s)+ m(g>t/f>s)]|t-s|^{p-2}dsdt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Is this argument correct?

$\left \| f -g\right \|_{p}^{p}=$

$\int_{0}^{\infty}m(|f-g|>t^{\frac{1}{p}}) dt\stackrel{c.o.v.}{=}$

$p\int_{0}^{\infty}m(|f-g|>t) t^{p-1}dt\stackrel{t=|u-s|}{=}$

$p\int_{0}^{\infty}m(|f-g|>t-s) |t-s|^{p-1}dt\stackrel{h=\int\frac{dh}{ds}ds}{=}$

$p(p-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t}[m(\{x:f>t\}-\{x:g>s\})+ m(\{x:g>t\}-\{x:f>s\})]|t-s|^{p-2}dsdt$

f,g are non-negative functions in $L^{p}(R^{n})$ where $1<p<\infty$.

thanks

Comment: any comments? Do you need more information?

Comment: Yeah, it would be nice to know what you've tried, and it would be nice if you TeXed the formulas nicely. At first glance it looks like an application of Fubini with a characteristic function.

Comment: doubt it. I am starting with one integral.

Comment: I think it's some sort of change of variables. But I can't find how to differentiate measures.

Comment: is this really that hard?

Comment: Note that you used Fubini with a characteristic function to get the first equality. The bounds of integration the third equality are wrong -- when $t = 0$, $u = s$. Finally, as written, the last line does not even make sense, though I suppose you meant the quotient of the measures of sets (rather than the measure of the quotient). Perhaps ask yourself what to make of $\frac{d}{ds}\mu(\{f > s\})$?

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out and purposefully glossed it over it. I opened a question for it but no answer came.

Comment: I didn't mean quotient, I meant removing.

Comment: So by $A - B$, you mean $A \cap B^c$?

Comment: @snarski  yes. But still any ideas for differentiating the level set?

Answer (score 1):

$\left \| f-g \right \|_{p}^{p}=$

$\int_{\{f>g\}}(f-g)^{p}dx+\int_{\{g>f\}}(g-f)^{p}dx$. Let's look at $\int_{\{f>g\}}(f-g)^{p}dx$.

$=p\int_{\{f>g\}}\int_{g(x)}^{f(x)}(t-g(x))^{p-1}dtdx$

$\stackrel{h=\int \frac{dh}{ds}ds}{=}(-1)p(p-1)\int_{\{f>g\}}\int_{g(x)}^{f(x)}\int_{t}^{g(x)}(t-s)^{p-2}dsdtdx=$.

$(-1)p(p-1)\int_{\{f>g\}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\chi_{f(x)\geq t\geq g(x)}\int_{t}^{0} \chi_{g(x)\geq s} (t-s)^{p-2}dsdtdx=$

$(-1)p(p-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{t}^{0}\int_{\{f>g\}} \chi_{\{f(x)>t\}\cap \{g(x)\geq s\}} (t-s)^{p-2}dsdtdx=$

$(-1)p(p-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{t}^{0}m(\{f(x)>t\}\cap \{g(x)\geq s\}) (t-s)^{p-2}dsdtdx\stackrel{switch~bounds}{=}$

$p(p-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t}m(\{f(x)>t\}\cap \{g(x)\geq s\}) (t-s)^{p-2}dsdtdx$.

We get similar result for other i.e. $p(p-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t}m(\{g(x)>t\}\cap \{f(x)\geq s\}) (t-s)^{p-2}dsdtdx$. Thus,

$p(p-1)\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{t}[m(\{f>t\}/\{g>s\})+ m(\{g>t\}/\{x:f>s\})]|t-s|^{p-2}dsdt$